# SD Card questions about read/write

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, sd-card

Good morning,

I have been cloning Raspberry Pi's SD Cards for a "write heavy" software that I have programmed. This leads to the SD Card being unable to write, making it "readonly". Since I can still copy / interact with the SD Card, I have made a clone image of it and I would like to know:

1) Is cloning the SD Card image safe?

2) Considering that the SD Card is now unable to write to persistent memory, but only to read from it, will the new SD Card be readonly?

3) If I clone an SD Card with, say, 1000 writes left, to a new SD Card that I just took out of the box, will I get just 1000 writes or all the possible writes from the new card?

4) What is the safest way to clone an image and retain all the writes from the new card while still having a backup of the SD Card image installed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is totally safe to clone the card as the reason you can no longer write to it is physical degradation of the memory chip itself.

1) Yes, as long as it is readable.

2) New card will have a full lifetime as specified by manufacturer

3) New card, new "lives" on it ;)

4) The "writes" are due to physical limitations of the memory chip.

I hope this helps!